# Hangouts bot, create room and add members

Tags: google-hangouts

Looking for a way to auto-create chat rooms in hangouts and auto invite some users in this room.
It is possible to do this with Hangoutbot?

Comment: Please try to pay a bit attention to how you write your question. your title alone has a typo and a missing space. Taking more time to write your question (also share some of your code, be more specific with your question) will make it easier for someone to take some of his time to answer your question. Also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/rest-api), there is no way to [create chat rooms](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces) or [add members to a room](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members) programmatically. All these actions can only be done using the UI.